# Replace returns wrong capturing group

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
,'','a','bc','def','ghi','lmn','op','qr','stu'
```

I'm trying to replace groups of 5 with the match and a line break for easy readability. So, I'm trying to do a regex match and replace.

Find What: `([\,]+[\']+[A-Z]{0,3}[\']+){5}`
Replace With: `\1\r\n`

The above in Notepad++ (version 6.8.8) will find/match

```
,'','a','bc','def','ghi'
```

but it replaces it with

```
,'ghi'[CR][LF]
```

I've also tried replacing with `\1\2\3\4\5\r\n`, and it yields the exact same result. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the output you're expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting it to replace `,'','a','bc','def','ghi'` with `,'','a','bc','def','ghi'[CR][LF]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Replace With: $0\r\n` ended up working I guess \1 was for versions before 6.

Comment: Nope - \1 is a first capturing group ([\,]+[\']+[A-Z]{0,3}[\']+) which you are matching 5 times, so \1 in replace capture the last match. (([\,]+[\']+[A-Z]{0,3}[\']+)) capture group is what you have been expected to match \1 while \2 is still the last '...' in line. However you have found better RegEx anyway...